# Triple tap gesture cannot be activated when programming PDF Viewer for iOS [Swift, iOS 15]

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, pdfview

#### I am trying to create a PDF Viewer, where users can triple-tap to select a word.

I would like to have it without conflicting with a double-tap gesture of the `PDFViewer` so that users can double-tap to autozoom.

However, I cannot activate the triple-tap using the following code.

```
let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapGesture(_:)))
tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
pdfView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
```

For some reason, double-tap can be activated when specifying `tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2`. However, this disturbs the double-tap gesture and I cannot use the autozoom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by implementing [shouldBeRequiredToFailBy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624222-gesturerecognizer) delegate method:

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(
        _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
    ) -> Bool {
        if let tapGestureRecognizer = otherGestureRecognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer,
           tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 2
        {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

And set the delegate to your gesture recognizer:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapGesture))
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
tapGesture.delegate = self
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much, @Philipdukhov!